# Problem with php exported xls file in Open Office

Tags: php

I am using PHP to export html table layout into excel format (.xls), well the html format opens up fine in Excel but distorted in OpenOffice..

do i have to add any special config to make html format work in OpenOffice?

Any suggesion would be helpful..

I use the below code

```
header("Content-Type: application/ms-excel"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=invoice.xls");
```

Comment: What are you using to export to the excel format?

Comment: I am using PHP Script.. are you asking about the script?

Comment: The title says CSV, are you sending a CSV file with a xls filename/excel header? Why not just send CSV, OpenOffice usually asks how the CSV file it set up when you open one (ie , vs ; etc)

Comment: You've mentioned `csv` `.xls` and `html` Which one are we talking about?

Comment: What's the distortion in OpenOffice you mention?

Comment: the html output is printed as it is.. without any formation..

Comment: I've never seen that -- possibly because I'm not 'exporting as xls'. I call my files *something.xls* but they're actually simple html tables with very little formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It's my practice to create HTML tables and save them as files with names like something.xls

Then both Excel and OpenOffice will open them as spreadsheets.

I don't use PHP, I use Perl, but no Content headers are involved.

Comment: This is bad practice. You should export to the correct file type: CSV is probably best, but you can export to XLS if you need formatting, or just save as HTML. Then you can open the HTML file in OOo or Excel if you want to and it will handle that fine.

Comment: i am working with PHP, and need to export data in excel format with html in it

Comment: @mjec, I realise it's not ideal, but saving my files as HTML tables allows me to retain a little formatting. TH elements look bold. I don't need anything else, but saving as CSV would give no formatting at all and my (company intranet) users would be confused.

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing the hint pavium. Didn't know that one so far. And looks like it's better that way then to provide CSV files with the .XLS file ending.